# Visual Basic UI Designing using HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vb6

I am designing a desktop application using Visual Basic 6, and I want its UI to look awesome. I was thinking whether there could be any way to use HTML/CSS/JQuery to design interactive UI elements (its possible by using the browser control to display HTML, but after a click (say) on a HTML element, I still need to call my VB function to perform the task, I cant't do that using Javascript. Besides, the Browser control is based on IE which is better not used as it doesn't support most of JQuery/CSS. So, basically what I want is:

1. An ActiveX control for VBb based on webkit engine, to display HTML
2. A way for javascript functions to call my VB functions

Comment: Do you wanna design it using only VB? Coz, there are many ports of Gecko (Firefox) and WebKit (Chrome) browsers available for this context and moreover, they run in all platforms. :)

Comment: "look awesome"? If you want it to look like a webapp, make a webapp. If you want a desktop app, it should look like a desktop app.

Comment: VB6 is for creating Windows applications.  These are expected to follow UI standards.  Many attempts at muleskinning "awesomeness" result in applications that look truly sad or become *unusable* at high DPI settings or when a user must use a low-vision color/font/etc. scheme.  If you want to stand out consider adding *function* over form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your UI to "look awesome" then VB6 is not the tool for you.

Out of the box it looks quite dated and this isn't that surprising since it hasn't had an update since around 1998.

You can make it look more modern but I think (IMHO) you will soon find the need to buy some third party controls to give it the look and feel you want.

We have used the [CodeJock control suite](http://www.codejock.com/products/suitepro/?platform=com) - a lot of these controls support 'markup' styling which is similar to xaml and can make a VB6 app look quite modern (ribbon bar interface, rounded corner button with mouseover effects etc)